# Actionbaractivity error

Tags: android, android-actionbar

> ```
>  public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     try
>     {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     System.out.println("here");
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);        
>         Toolbar mToolBar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
>         if(mToolBar != null)
>         {
>             setSupportActionBar(mToolBar);
>             getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
>             getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
>             mToolBar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void onClick(View v) {
>                     //What to do on back clicked
>                     finish();
>                 }
>             });         //this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE); 
>         }
>         setTitle("LOGIN");
>     }
>     catch(Exception e)
>     {
>         System.out.println(" "+e.getMessage());
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> }
>
> ```
>       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout12"
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="wrap_content"
> android:orientation="vertical" >
> <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:background="@android:color/white"
>     android:minHeight="56dp"
>     app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
>     app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitle" />
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:id="@+id/lais"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
>     android:orientation="horizontal" >
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/image1"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
>         android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
>         android:padding="10dp" >
>     </ImageView>
> </RelativeLayout>
> <ScrollView
>     android:id="@+id/scrollV"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:layout_below="@id/lais"
>     android:fadingEdge="none"
>     android:fillViewport="true" >
>           <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
>     android:layout_margin="20dp"
>     android:orientation="vertical" >
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:singleLine="true"
>         android:text="Username"
>         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
>         android:textSize="14sp" />
>     <EditText
>         android:id="@+id/usernameField"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
>         android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bg_username"
>         android:drawablePadding="5dp"
>         android:inputType="text"
>         android:singleLine="true" >
>         <requestFocus />
>     </EditText>
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:singleLine="true"
>         android:text="Password"
>         android:textColor="@android:color/white"
>         android:textSize="14sp" />
>     <EditText
>         android:id="@+id/passwordField"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
>         android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bg_password"
>         android:drawablePadding="5dp"
>         android:ems="10"
>         android:inputType="textPassword" />
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:orientation="vertical" >
>         <Button
>             android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_gravity="right"
>             android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
>             android:layout_weight="1"
>             android:text="Submit"
>             android:textSize="14sp" />        
>     </LinearLayout>
> </LinearLayout>
> </ScrollView>
> ```

I get the following error  android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.internal.widget.NativeActionModeAwareLayout. I still cannot figure out what the error is bout.

Comment: What line are you getting this error on?

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout12"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:minHeight="56dp"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitle" />
```

---

Try like above